# Set polyline icon on mouseover

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I don't want the cursor icon to change to `pointer` when hovering a polyline, I want it to keep it the *palm icon* ([.cur file](http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/openhand.cur)) which is used on the rest of the map. I have read many posts about setting cursor to a polygon/polyline but I can't figure out how to implement it in my example: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T4xFF/)** (stripped to bare bones)

I believe I should use the `draggableCursor` property and assiciate it with a `mouseover` listener but it's not working:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseover', function(event) {
    map.setOptions({ draggableCursor: 'url(http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/openhand.cur), crosshair' });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will setting the polyline to `{clickable:false}` work?  Or do you need mouse events?

Comment: This made the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my question in case someone finds it useful someday. As geocodezip pointed out, the solution is very simple: set `clickable:false` so the polyline is defined as:

```
path: lines[i],
strokeColor: '#ff0000',
strokeOpacity: 1.0,
strokeWeight: 2,
clickable: false
```

Here is updated **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T4xFF/1/)**.